# R - sequence calculations both forward and backward looking

Tags: r, data.table, seq

I have the following data frame:

```
id = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C")
month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)
amount = c(0,0,10,0,0,0,0,10,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,10,10,0)

df <- data.frame(id, month, amount)
```

What I need to do (by ID) is:
Calculate (by way of a negative number) the difference in months between zero and non-zero "amount" rows until such time as the "amount" equals 0. When this happens, the time = 0. THEN, once an "amount" exceeds zero in the sequence, the calculation (by way of a positive number) will look back and calculate the difference in months between non-zero and the historical zero "amount" row.

The solution would look like:

```
solution = c(-2,-1,0,1,2,3,-1,0,1,0,1,2,-3,-2,-1,0,0,1)
```

As you can probably tell, its pretty tough to search for this multi-layered problem. Ideally the answer would be using data.table as i'm dealing with millions of rows, but dplyr would also suit my needs.

Any help appreciated.

S.

Comment: your vectors are of different lengths, how can you expect to obtain rectangular data, such as DF, from that?

Comment: You might be having trouble getting it into a data.frame because you only have 5 A, B, and Cs. Should have 6.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[, g := rleid(id, amount != 0)]
DT[, g_id := g - g[1L], by=id]
DT[, v :=  
  if (g_id == 0L) 
    -(.N:1)
  else if (g_id %% 2 == 0)
    1:.N
  else 
    0L
, by=.(id, g_id)]

all.equal(DT$v, solution) # TRUE
```

To see how it works:

```
    id month amount  g g_id  v
 1:  A     1      0  1    0 -2
 2:  A     2      0  1    0 -1
 3:  A     3     10  2    1  0
 4:  A     4      0  3    2  1
 5:  A     5      0  3    2  2
 6:  A     6      0  3    2  3
 7:  B     1      0  4    0 -1
 8:  B     2     10  5    1  0
 9:  B     3      0  6    2  1
10:  B     4     10  7    3  0
11:  B     5      0  8    4  1
12:  B     6      0  8    4  2
13:  C     1      0  9    0 -3
14:  C     2      0  9    0 -2
15:  C     3      0  9    0 -1
16:  C     4     10 10    1  0
17:  C     5     10 10    1  0
18:  C     6      0 11    2  1
```

You can drop the extra columns with `DT[, c("g", "g_id") := NULL]`.

Comment: This works great until this comes about: structure(list(DIAMOND_ID = c(10001123L, 10001123L, 10001123L,10001123L, 10001123L, 10001123L, 10001123L, 10001123L, 10001123L,10001123L, 10001123L), PREMIUM_MONTH = 201301:201311, CLAIMS_PAID = c(0,0, 0, 38.4, 0, 38.4, 276, 80.8, 34.4, 0, 30.4), g = c(14L, 14L,14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L), g_id = c(0L, 0L,0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), v = c(-3L, -2L, -1L, 0L,1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("DIAMOND_ID", "PREMIUM_MONTH","CLAIMS_PAID", "g", "g_id", "v"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L))

Comment: The results should be: -3,-2,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0

Comment: @ScottHunter Ok. I've changed it to `rleid(id, amount != 0)`, which may fix it. I haven't translated your different col names and tested it, though. Hopefully, the steps are transparent enough that you can extend them if the problem gets more complicated. If not, maybe update your question (if the change is minor enough that it won't invalidate the other answer) or post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyr` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_new <- df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    # identify non-zero instances
    mutate(temp = ifelse(amount != 0, month, NA)) %>% 
    # fill down first
    fill(temp, .direction = "down") %>% 
    # fill up after
    fill(temp, .direction = "up") %>% 
    # calculate difference
    mutate(solution = month - temp) %>% 
    # remove temp
    select(-temp)
```

Result

```
#        id month amount solution
#     <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1       A     1      0       -2
# 2       A     2      0       -1
# 3       A     3     10        0
# 4       A     4      0        1
# 5       A     5      0        2
# 6       A     6      0        3
# 7       B     1      0       -1
# 8       B     2     10        0
# 9       B     3      0        1
# 10      B     4     10        0
# 11      B     5      0        1
# 12      B     6      0        2
# 13      C     1      0       -3
# 14      C     2      0       -2
# 15      C     3      0       -1
# 16      C     4     10        0
# 17      C     5     10        0
# 18      C     6      0        1
```